# Scatter Chart in analog clock

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I have a json data array like this:

```
var data=[
{"someProperty":"number","time":"2014-12-11T09:24:39.000Z"}, 
{"someProperty":"number","time":"2014-12-11T09:27:39.000Z"}, 
{"someProperty":"number","time":"2014-12-11T09:30:39.000Z"}, ..... 
]
```

I need to draw a circle for each one in the array (with radius of "someProperty")
and put them in an analog clock according the time.
I found a picture similar to my problem here:

[image]

but with no code :(

I use d3.js for it.
I succeeded in doing it by using rotate but then all the circles where on the circumference and intersect each other.
I want to put them across the radius in order to avoid collision. 
I see some examples of collision detection like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1747543
but I don't see there any option to control the x,y position like I want.

Comment: Take a look at this page. I think this is what you're after. http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/1ca23ee9588580d768aa

Comment: If you dont want to drag them yourself you should concider positioning them yourself and not use cpu expensive libraries to rotate and detect colision etc.. It's not really clear what you want. If they have to be draggable etc? If not.. maybe you should read something about basic geometry instead of trying such heavy libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question right, "someProperty" will provide the radius value, and "time" provides the angle.

I would suggest transforming these datum to polar coordnates as described here: [d3.js Plot elements using polar coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790702/d3-js-plot-elements-using-polar-coordinates)

Theta would be the angle converted from "time". r would be "someProperty"