# Draw Complicated Shapes in D3

Tags: d3.js, svg, graphics

I am trying to draw an irregular, petal shape for a D3 animation, but I cannot find any understandable documentation for odd shapes in SVG-format.  How might I go about creating such a shape?  [image: Rose-petal shape]

Comment: This question will soon be closed, but before that, this is what I'd do: using Inkscape or illustrator, I'd draw the shape. Then, I'd copy the SVG and paste it in a `var`, and use that var for the "d" attribute of the path.

Comment: I would use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790702/d3-js-plot-elements-using-polar-coordinates) to draw a polar curve and use [this](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa2013/Thurston/Write-Ups/Write-up%2011/Polar_Petals.html) to get the petal shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something like this:

```
<svg>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M21,34.328C21,15.693,32.477,0.515,50.124,0.515
    C67.77,0.515,79,16.928,79,34.328c0,17.399-29,65.157-29,65.157S21,52.962,21,34.328z"/>
</svg>
```

And use as definition (defs) for future reference. Look [here](http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/2b1d992dfb66542ec1e2)

and here: [Is it possible to import svg shapes in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092976/is-it-possible-to-import-svg-shapes-in-d3-js)

If you want do it by hand, here's the Paths Tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Here the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/Meajyx)